# How to avoid code duplication in JavaScript in the attached snippet?

Tags: javascript, callback, overloading

I am trying to find the Weather using `Open Weather` map and I have 2 methods, `findWeatherByLocation` and `findWeatherByCity`. I am assuming that `JavaScript` doesn't support `method overloading` and hence the 2 different names. Both methods accept a `callback` function that will be triggered and does the same thing.

```
function findWeatherForCity(senderID, city, countryCode, callback) {
    //Lets configure and request
    request({
        url: constants.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_BASE_URL, //URL to hit
        qs: {
            q: city + ',' + countryCode,
            appid: constants.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY
        }, //Query string data
        method: 'GET', //Specify the method
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            let weather = getWeatherReport(JSON.parse(body));
            callback(weather ? weather : null);
        }
        else {
            console.error(response.error);
            callback(null);
        }
    });
}

/*
 lat, lon coordinates of the location of your interest   
 * http://openweathermap.org/current
 */

function findWeatherForLocation(senderID, location, callback) {
    //Lets configure and request
    request({
        url: constants.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_BASE_URL, //URL to hit
        qs: {
            lat: location.lat,
            lon: location.lon,
            appid: constants.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY
        }, //Query string data
        method: 'GET', //Specify the method
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            let report = getWeatherReport(JSON.parse(body));
            callback(report ? report : null);
        }
        else {
            console.error(response.error)
            callback(null);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, the `function(error, response, body)` does the same thing in both places. If I make a separate `function(error, response, body)` which is common for both `findWeatherByCity` and `findWeatherByLocation`, how do I trigger the `callback`?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this question doesn't belong to StackOverflow but here is how you can do this:

```
function responseHandler (error, response, body, callback) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        let weather = getWeatherReport(JSON.parse(body));
        callback(weather ? weather : null);
    }
    else {
        console.error(response.error);
        callback(null);
    }
}

function findWeatherForCity(senderID, city, countryCode, callback) {
    //Lets configure and request
    request({
        url: constants.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_BASE_URL, //URL to hit
        qs: {
            q: city + ',' + countryCode,
            appid: constants.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY
        }, //Query string data
        method: 'GET', //Specify the method
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        responseHandler(error, response, body, callback)
    });
}

/*
 lat, lon coordinates of the location of your interest
 * http://openweathermap.org/current
 */

function findWeatherForLocation(senderID, location, callback) {
    //Lets configure and request
    request({
        url: constants.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_BASE_URL, //URL to hit
        qs: {
            lat: location.lat,
            lon: location.lon,
            appid: constants.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY
        }, //Query string data
        method: 'GET', //Specify the method
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        responseHandler(error, response, body, callback)
    });
}
```

Comment: with great respect this doesnt look nice, errorHandler handles success aswell?? obviously the code can be refactored alot more than this aswell...

Comment: I quite don't understand this @AhmadBamieh, your given code is also handling the success as well as failure.

Answer (score 1):

I have used promises to refactor the callbacks and tidy the code, but you can replace them with callbacks although I don't recommend it (it's 2016 already).

```js
/* you are not using senderID anywhere but i left it cuz you had it.*/
function findWeather(senderID, queryType, options) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var queryObj = {
      appid: constants.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY
    };
    if (queryType === 'city') {
      queryObj.q = options.city + ',' + options.countryCode;
    } else if (queryType === 'location') {
      queryObj.lat= options.lat;
      queryObj.lon= options.lon;
      }
    } else {
      reject('no valid queryType');
    }

    request({
      url: constants.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_BASE_URL,
      qs: queryObj,
      method: 'GET'
    }, function(err, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        let report = getWeatherReport(JSON.parse(body));
        resolve(report ? report : null);
      } else {
        reject(response.error);
      }
    });
  });
}

/*USAGE*/
findWeather(1, 'city', {
    city: 'Ramallah',
    countryCode: '00970'
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

findWeather(1, 'location', {
    lat: 1,
    lon: 2
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```